# Authentication Issue when using Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm currently working on an android app using android studio and the google cloud endpoints module with android studio. So I'm trying to add User authentication through the Firebase Auth so I can provide my users with sign-in options from different users. However whenever I try to add the authentication code to the API in my endpoint class. The apiIssuer and ApiissuerAudience are always unresolved. I've tried everything and I can't fix the issue so I'm assuming I didn't do or did something wrong to affect this part of the code.

```
package com.example.Kendrickod.myapplication.backend;

import com.example.Kendrickod.myapplication.backend.domain.Profile;
import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Named;

/**
* Defines event APIs.
*/


/** An endpoint class we are exposing */
@Api(name = "event",
    version = "v1",
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain =
     "backend.myapplication.Kendrickod.example.com",
            ownerName = "backend.myapplication.Kendrickod.example.com",
            packagePath = ""),
    authenticators = {EspAuthenticator.class},
    issuers = {
            @ApiIssuer(
                    name = "firebase",
                    issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/YOUR-PROJECT-ID",
                    jwksUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
    },
    issuerAudiences = {
            @ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", audiences = "YOUR-PROJECT-ID")
    },
    clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, Constants.IOS_CLIENT_ID},
    audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE})

 public class EventApi {


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include this library!

```
com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework-auth:1.0.2
```

it seems trivial but not easy to find out ... I got to try them all.

if you use Android Studio, go to Build / Edit library and dependencies click on the "+" and search for "endpoints-framework"

Comment: sorry, you also have to import com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework library, and pay attention to put them BEFORE all the other library ... that's all!

Comment: Thank you! That made it work. I had a feeling it had to do with my library.